# mark the selected date from date picker in the calendar

Tags: android, date, datetime, custom-controls

I want to mark the date in the custom calendar which is selected in the date picker automatically. My date picker is in one activity and calendar is the other activity. So, I also want that when i click on the save button after selecting date from the date picker it should automatically open my custom calendar with the selected date marked in it. Thanks in advance.Do let me know if I need to give any more information here.
this is my code for the main activity where i m selecting date and time through date and time picker:

```
package com.example.scheduler;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public TextView mDateDisplay;
public Button mPickDate;
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;
private TextView mTimeDisplay;
private Button mPickTime;
private Button mSubmit;
private int mhour;
private int mminute;
private Date date;
public EditText mName;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDateDisplay =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
    mPickDate =(Button)findViewById(R.id.datepicker);
    mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    mPickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timepicker);
    mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

    //Pick time's click event listener
    mPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }

    });

    //PickDate's click event listener// 
    mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

        }
    });


    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mhour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mminute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


}

//update date//    
private void updateDate() {

      mDateDisplay.setText(
        new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mDay).append("/")
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("/")
                .append(mYear).append(" "));
    showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

     }

  //update time//    
public void updatetime()
{
    mTimeDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    .append(pad(mhour)).append(":")
                    .append(pad(mminute))); 
}

        private static String pad(int c) {
                    if (c >= 10)
                            return String.valueOf(c);
                        else
                                return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
                        }




//Datepicker dialog generation // 

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateDate();
        }
    };


 // Timepicker dialog generation//
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
         new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                mhour = hourOfDay;
                mminute = minute;
                updatetime();
                //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alert.class);
                //startActivity(intent);
                String Date = mDateDisplay.getText().toString();
                String Time = mTimeDisplay.getText().toString();
                String Name = mName.getText().toString();
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Alert.class); 
                intent1.putExtra("mDateDisplay", Date); 
                intent1.putExtra("mTimeDisplay", Time);
                intent1.putExtra("mName", Name);
                startActivity(intent1);


            }


        };

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        mDateSetListener,
                        mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    mTimeSetListener, mhour, mminute, false);

        }
        return null;
    }

}


Now below is my calendar adapter and calendar view classes:

package com.example.scheduler;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    private java.util.Calendar month;
    public GregorianCalendar pmonth; // calendar instance for previous month
    /**
     * calendar instance for previous month for getting complete view
     */
    public GregorianCalendar pmonthmaxset;
    private GregorianCalendar selectedDate;
    int firstDay;
    int maxWeeknumber;
    int maxP;
    int calMaxP;
    int lastWeekDay;
    int leftDays;
    int mnthlength;
    String itemvalue, curentDateString;
    DateFormat df;

    private ArrayList<String> items;
    public static List<String> dayString;
    private View previousView;

    public CalendarAdapter(Context c, GregorianCalendar monthCalendar) {
        CalendarAdapter.dayString = new ArrayList<String>();
         Locale.setDefault( Locale.US );
        month = monthCalendar;
        selectedDate = (GregorianCalendar) monthCalendar.clone();
        mContext = c;
        month.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        curentDateString = df.format(selectedDate.getTime());
        refreshDays();
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
        for (int i = 0; i != items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).length() == 1) {
                items.set(i, "0" + items.get(i));
            }
        }
        this.items = items;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return dayString.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dayString.get(position);`enter code here`
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new view for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        TextView dayView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                    // attributes
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);

        }
        dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        // separates daystring into parts.
        String[] separatedTime = dayString.get(position).split("-");
        // taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02
        String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");
        // checking whether the day is in current month or not.
        if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (position < firstDay)) {
            // setting offdays to white color.
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dayView.setClickable(false);
            dayView.setFocusable(false);
        } else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (position > 28)) {
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dayView.setClickable(false);
            dayView.setFocusable(false);
        } else {
            // setting curent month's days in blue color.
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        if (dayString.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {
            setSelected(v);
            previousView = v;
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }
        dayView.setText(gridvalue);

        // create date string for comparison
        String date = dayString.get(position);

        if (date.length() == 1) {
            date = "0" + date;
        }
        String monthStr = "" + (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
        if (monthStr.length() == 1) {
            monthStr = "0" + monthStr;
        }

        // show icon if date is not empty and it exists in the items array
        ImageView iw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
        if (date.length() > 0 && items != null && items.contains(date)) {
            iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            iw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return v;
    }

    public View setSelected(View view) {
        if (previousView != null) {
            previousView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }
        previousView = view;
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_cel_selectl);
        return view;
    }

    public void refreshDays() {
        // clear items
        items.clear();
        dayString.clear();
        Locale.setDefault( Locale.US );
        pmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
        // month start day. ie; sun, mon, etc
        firstDay = month.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        // finding number of weeks in current month.
        maxWeeknumber = month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        // allocating maximum row number for the gridview.
        mnthlength = maxWeeknumber * 7;
        maxP = getMaxP(); // previous month maximum day 31,30....
        calMaxP = maxP - (firstDay - 1);// calendar offday starting 24,25 ...
        /**
         * Calendar instance for getting a complete gridview including the three
         * month's (previous,current,next) dates.
         */
        pmonthmaxset = (GregorianCalendar) pmonth.clone();
        /**
         * setting the start date as previous month's required date.
         */
        pmonthmaxset.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calMaxP + 1);

        /**
         * filling calendar gridview.
         */
        for (int n = 0; n < mnthlength; n++) {

            itemvalue = df.format(pmonthmaxset.getTime());
            pmonthmaxset.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
            dayString.add(itemvalue);

        }
    }

    private int getMaxP() {
        int maxP;
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
                .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            pmonth.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                    month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            pmonth.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
        }
        maxP = pmonth.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return maxP;
    }

}

package com.example.scheduler;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CalendarView extends Activity {

    public GregorianCalendar month, itemmonth;// calendar instances.

    public CalendarAdapter adapter;// adapter instance
    public Handler handler;// for grabbing some event values for showing the dot
                            // marker.
    public ArrayList<String> items; // container to store calendar items which
                                    // needs showing the event marker

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar);
         Locale.setDefault( Locale.US );
        month = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        itemmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();

        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new CalendarAdapter(this, month);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(calendarUpdater);

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));

        RelativeLayout previous = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.previous);

        previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setPreviousMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
        });

        RelativeLayout next = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.next);
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setNextMonth();
                refreshCalendar();

            }
        });

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
                String selectedGridDate = CalendarAdapter.dayString
                        .get(position);
                String[] separatedTime = selectedGridDate.split("-");
                String gridvalueString = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*",
                        "");// taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02.
                int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);
                // navigate to next or previous month on clicking offdays.
                if ((gridvalue > 10) && (position < 8)) {
                    setPreviousMonth();
                    refreshCalendar();
                } else if ((gridvalue < 7) && (position > 28)) {
                    setNextMonth();
                    refreshCalendar();
                }
                ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);

                showToast(selectedGridDate);

            }
        });
    }

    protected void setNextMonth() {
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
                .getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            month.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + 1),
                    month.getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
        }

    }

    protected void setPreviousMonth() {
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
                .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            month.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                    month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
        }

    }

    protected void showToast(String string) {
        Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void refreshCalendar() {
        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

        adapter.refreshDays();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        handler.post(calendarUpdater); // generate some calendar items

        title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));
    }

    public Runnable calendarUpdater = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            items.clear();

            // Print dates of the current week
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.US);
            String itemvalue;
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                itemvalue = df.format(itemmonth.getTime());
                itemmonth.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
                items.add("2012-09-12");
                items.add("2012-10-07");
                items.add("2012-10-15");
                items.add("2012-10-20");
                items.add("2012-11-30");
                items.add("2012-11-28");
            }

            adapter.setItems(items);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };




    }
```

Comment: Pass selected date using intent to your custom calendar Activity

Comment: I have seen various intents and tried too.. but its not doing the tast can you give me the exact code as I am new to android so may be I am not able to find out the stuff that i want to or may be something I am missing. So, I request you to give me the exact code please. thanks

Comment: Please post your code so that i can understand it better.

Comment: please check I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Hi aditi try my below code

```
 if (dayString.get(position).equals(Your selected date)) {
            setSelected(v);
            previousView = v;
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }
```

instead of current date just pass your selected date so that it will get selected automatically.
Any doubt let me know..